# SQL Number of Occurrences, summary Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as below,

```
Product Promotion exists (Y/N)  Week
    A   Y   1
    B   Y   1
    C   Y   1
    A   Y   2
    B   Y   2
    C   N   2
    A   Y   3
    B   Y   3
    C   Y   3
    A   Y   4
    B   Y   4
    C   N   4
```

I want to see an Promition exists combination Output on total table. Something like

```
A, B - 4
B,C  - 2
A,C - 2
```

Since this is Just for 3 products looks simple.. I am looking at some thousands of records, and looking for same combinations where total count of occurrence is greater than some number. If taking the above example, if that count is 4.. then my output should be

```
A,B - 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT p1, p2, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM (
  SELECT t1.Product AS p1, t2.Product AS p2
  FROM mytable AS t1
  JOIN mytable AS t2 
    ON t1.Week = t2.Week AND 
       t1.Product < t2.Product AND 
       t1.Exists = 'Y' AND t2.Exists = 'Y') AS t
  GROUP BY p1, p2     
  ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

To get only pairs exceeding a certain value, just wrap the above in a subquery and add a `WHERE cnt >= someValue`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad30e/1)